# How do I connect github to JIRA?

Tags: git, github, jira

I've been trying to find a way to update JIRA when I commit to github.

It doesn't look like there are any service hooks to do it at github, but you never know, someone might have a ninja way, so I thought I'd ask.

Comment: For [JIRA Studio](http://www.atlassian.com/hosted/studio/), there is a way to integrate with GitHub: [Integrating GitHub with JIRA Studio](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRASTUDIO/Integrating+GitHub+with+JIRA+Studio). I haven't found a similarly simple way for standalone JIRA, but I assume there should be a way to do that.

Answer (score 43):

**UPDATE**

For integrating with Bitbucket, check out the following link:

[Linking Bitbucket and GitHub accounts to JIRA](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/linking-bitbucket-cloud-and-github-accounts-to-jira-software-300814271.html)

**ORIGINAL POST**

[JIRA GitHub Connector](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.jira.plugins.github) is deprecated:

> This plugin has been superseded by the JIRA DVCS Connector, which includes GitHub functionality.

So to connect Jira to github use [JIRA DVCS Connector for Bitbucket and GitHub](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.jira.plugins.jira-bitbucket-connector-plugin):

> You can connect Bitbucket or GitHub accounts with JIRA using the free JIRA DVCS Connector plugin. This plugin comes with JIRA OnDemand.   For JIRA download users, this is a system plugin that you can install. Using the DVCS connector, you can:
>
> - Link all or a subset of your existing repositories (both public and private to JIRA).
> - Create new repositories and have them link automatically to JIRA.
> - Reference JIRA issues from DVCS commit message and have those commits appear in the issue's Commits tab in JIRA.
> - Transition issues through a JIRA OnDemand workflow (for example, Close, Reopen, and so forth)  using smart commit messages.

check out [Using the JIRA DVCS Connector Plugin](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+the+JIRA+DVCS+Connector+Add-on) for more information.

Comment: The Atlassian examples are most specific about Bitbucket and rather hazy on Github enterprise.

Comment: "The JIRA DVCS Connector add-on has been retired and incorporated into the standalone JIRA Software application" quoth one of your links

Comment: FYI, the updated link doesn't mention Github on the page (anymore?)

Comment: @AlexanderF. can you check this: https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/connect-jira-cloud-to-github-814188429.html
if works you, please let me know, and I'll update the answer

Comment: Is it compulsory to have an enterprise account (/ paid account) in github to connect it with Jira?

Comment: Just figured it out. You can use the free account. To install Jira in Github, the following link helped me. https://github.com/integrations/jira

Answer (score 9):

Atlassian has a plugin on GitHub to connect the two:

https://github.com/atlassian/jira-github-connector-plugin

Looks like it adds a project setting to point to a GitHub project and a tab that will show your commits in GitHub.

Comment: Note that that project has been superseded by JIRA's DVCS connector. You can find details for that here: https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.jira.plugins.bitbucket. Now if you have a JIRA 'OnDemand' instance already hosted for you, it is already integrated. You need to configure it. Instructions for that are here: http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Linking+your+JIRA+Project+to+a+Repository

Comment: That link has changed, it's now https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AOD/Linking+a+Bitbucket+or+GitHub+repository+with+JIRA+OnDemand

Comment: [The DVCS functionality is now just integrated into JIRA](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.jira.plugins.jira-bitbucket-connector-plugin/versions).

Answer (score 4):

In addition you can also define Webhooks on the GitHub site that do a POST-Request to other Webservers. Have a look here:
https://developer.github.com/webhooks/

On the JIRA  site, you have the Jira REST APIs with which you can edit or update or create or do pretty much anything with your Jira issues:
https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+APIs

Answer (score 2):

I just experienced the same issue and found the answers and the official reference web maybe need to be more specific for Github enterprise version.
If you are using the enterprise Github, you should:

1) Register the application under the enterprise's settings, not under the user's.

2) Suppose your JIRA site as http://myjira.com/jira which you can access your JIRA main page, then the Homapage URL and the Authorization callback URL should be the same as your JIRA site URL.

3) When add new account in JIRA, the Host field shoud be GitHub Enterprise, the Team or User Account should be the enterprise's name which can be found under the organization profile in Github.

4) The Host URL should be Github main page.

Then I think it should work for enterprise when connect the JIRA and github.

Comment: Unfortunately, JIRA's documentation is incorrect and prompts you to enter "Team or user" for GitHub. However, the correct way is to set it to your GitHub organization, if you are setting up an organization's JIRA-GitHub connector.

Answer (score 2):

If you visiting this page in 2016, and using Cloud JIRA, it is find here-

Application>>Integrations>>DVCS Accounts, instead of under Add Ons as mentioned in blog posts being thrown up by Google.

Answer (score 2):

I have made a small Chrome plugin recently which will edit GitHubs PR pages to show information on the linked Atlassian tickets.

It will require a PR title format of `[ISSUE-9485] Some description` but works pretty cool, if you ask me.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-jira-integration/faenbbkpfnklhncjianlfllkfekgghih

Source code is here: https://github.com/RobQuistNL/chrome-github-jira

**Screenshot:**
[image: Screenshot]

EDIT: 
It will also automatically create a "template" for your pull request, based on content / description of the ticket.

E.g. it will take items under the header "Acceptance Criteria" and post it as a checkable list, adds some description, a how to test, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this plugin https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1220080/smart-git-integration-for-jira Smart Git intagration for Jira add-on allows to connect your Jira project to Git with repository URL in a few clicks.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who are looking for **how to import the `Project` data from GitHub onto JIRA**, then you should go to this link: https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/importing-data-from-github-802592903.html

It gives you in dept instructions on how to do that. I was able to bring in everything and map bugs to bugs, etc. Even completed tasks came in.

If the link decides not to work one day, here is a summary which I take no credit for:

```
 1. Log in to JIRA as a user with the JIRA Administrators global permission.

 2. Choose  > System. Select Import & Export > External System Import to open the List item Import external projects page. 

 3. Select the Import button associated with the GitHub option to open the GitHub Import Wizard.

 4. On the GitHub Setup page, select which type of GitHub you are using. If you are using GitHub Enterprise you will also be required to provide your GitHub Enterprise URL. You also need to provide either your GitHub username and password, or a GitHub Personal Access Token. Note if you have used the GitHub import wizard before and saved a previous configuration file, you can select the configuration file here to speed up your import.

 5. Click Next.
  Have 2 factor authentication? Click here..
 The Authentication page displays, verifying your authentication has been successful. 

 6. Click Next. The Map projects page displays, and will show a list of all your public and private repositories, as well as any repositories you have starred.
```

Then you just select the projects you wants to add...and the rest is easy.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

#### Top post is deprecated.

2020 URL:
*$JIRAPROJECT*.atlassian.net/secure/admin/ConfigureDvcsOrganizations!default.jspa

```
If you're connecting a Jira Core project:
Choose [WHEEL icon TOP RIGHT corner] > Products.
Under INTEGRATIONS, select DVCS accounts.
Select Link Bitbucket Cloud account.
```

That page would also allow Gitlab connection

Comment: What post are you referring to?? "First Post" listed is dependent on the user's sort order (by upvotes, date, etc), and it changes over time depending on the number of upvotes and downvotes have been received. So your response is ambiguous. It is best left as a comment under the appropriate post. Also since it is not a self-contained answer, it is not considered an Answer according to SO guidelines (see help section). Please `edit` to make this a complete answer, or delete and repost as a comment, or a suggested edit to the post you are referencing. As is, this post may be removed by SO.