# Free, hosted, issue tracker with github integration

Tags: github, bug-tracking, issue-tracking, hosted

The Github issue tracker is not quite cutting the mustard for our (open-source, but professionally developed) project: it has the bizarre and crippling* restriction that non-owners can't assign labels or users to issues.

So we need a new issue tracker. We don't need a lot, but labels (for components, and to distinguish subprojects) and user assignation are pretty important. Integration with Github would be a real bonus, as would nice ease of use. It has to be hosted, and preferably free-as-in-beer (or at the very least, have no per-developer charge).

Is there anything that fits this bill? Pivotal Tracker looks nice but is more of an agile work tracker than an issue/bug tracker. Trying Lighthouse now, but Github integration (if possible) could be fiddly.

* Crippling because giving someone "ownership" status gives them the ability to delete the entire repository: issue permissions and code permissions are not distinguished.

Comment: We ended up using Lighthouse for that project - sort of satisfactory. We gave up on Github integration.

Answer (score 3):

FogBugz is free for up to two users and [supports GitHub](http://blog.fogcreek.com/fogbugz-github-integration/).  Pivotal Tracker is free if you leave your project public (not sure if that's possible) and it supports GitHub.  Jira is $10 and connects to [GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421647/how-do-i-connect-github-to-jira).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at [Brightlight](http://www.brightlightapp.com), it allows you to assign administrators and then they in turn can assign sub members to projects.

At the minute there is no Github integration but if you are willing to keep the issue tracking separate then it may be worth trying. It means that users won't be able to delete the Github repository.

Comment: It's not free. (These days, anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

Try EzSDLC, http://encodesoft.com/?page_id=77
This is very simple and lightweight
It however does not support GITHUB