# Github comment autolink to jira issue

Tags: git, hyperlink, jira, integration

I was using gerrit for our code review in my previous company. When we were commit changes to gerrit, we use to write in comment as `Closes: JIRA-1234`.

When this message post to gerrit, it shows link to JIRA issue, like `Closes:`[JIRA-1234](https://jira.com/browse/JIRA-1234). From git comment and git webpage, we can directly redirect to jira issue and we can change the workflow of that jira.

I joined new company, and they are not using gerrit. They have GitHub Enterprise setup. When I tried `Closes: JIRA-1234` in git commit, it not shows the link.

When I contacted our github admin team and asked them, is there any specific settings I have to enable in our GitHub organization to enable this features, they inform, for some teams its working, for our team, its not working.

I tried to contact and enable this, but not able to enable that features.

Is there any way to check, why its working for some team ? or how can I enable that for our team?

I created JIRA OAuth application.

[image: OAuth Application]

With this, I am able to see the branches and commits in JIRA `Development` section. I get a link to GitHub from JIRA.

[image: JIRA Commit and Pull request]

But reverse, like link from GitHub to JIRA was not there.

[image: GitHub comment without link]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible Jira is not part of the organisation your team is part of in your GitHUb EE instance: see "[Integrating JIRA with your organization's projects](https://help.github.com/articles/integrating-jira-with-your-organization-s-projects/)"

(As opposed to [connecting Jira to GitHub](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/connect-jira-cloud-to-github-814188429.html), which does work in your case)

---

Update Oct. 2019, you now can set up an autolink reference and GitHub will automatically create links (to external systems) for you.

See "[make Jira links clickable in GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58383541/6309)" (only for GitHub Pro, Team, and Enterprise plans).

Comment: VonC, as I mentioned in my question at last line, my organization in GitHub EE has OAuthApplication register for JIRA

Comment: @Nilesh Not the right one? OAuth instead of OAuth2?

Comment: VonC, we have only `OAuth Application` there is no option for `OAuth2`. I updated my question, you might get more detail of my situation.