# Github - creating link to my JIRA issue in commit message

Tags: github

Would someone please let me know if there is any way to create link to JIRA tickets in my github commit messages?

Comment: If you are using GitHub Pro, Team, or Enterprise plans, you have that option. See [my edited answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56896776/6309).

Answer (score 5):

You can try and follow "[Connect Jira Cloud to GitHub](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/connect-jira-cloud-to-github-814188429.html)", which allows for GitHub or GitHub Enterprise account to be linked to Jira Software.

> Your team gets to see their branches, commit messages and pull requests right in the context of the Jira Software issues they're working on
>
> When a developer makes a commit, they should add a Jira Software issue key to the commit message, like this:

```
git commit -m "PROJ-123 add a README file to the project."
git push origin <branchname>
```

---

Update Oct. 2019, you now can set up an autolink reference and GitHub will automatically create links (to external systems) for you.

See "[make Jira links clickable in GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58383541/6309)" (only for GitHub Pro, Team, and Enterprise plans).