# Connect branch to Jira issue and show all commits/pull requests

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, jira

It is possible to connect Github/Bitbucket to a Jira issue by adding the issue ID(fx. WEB-100) in the branch/commit/pull request name after some initial setup([How do I connect github to JIRA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421647/how-do-i-connect-github-to-jira)). That would look like so in Jira issue WEB-100 for branch WEB-100_some_branch and commit WEB-100_some_commit:

[image]

The problem is that it is easy to forget to add the ID in every commit making the commit unavailable in the Jira issue. My question is, if there is a way to force Jira to show everything related to a branch after it is connected(commits, pull request, etc.)?

Comment: From my experience with jira, no, you can't. It shows the branch, and you can click on the branch to see all its commits, whether they reference the issue or not, but it only counts specific commits in the "1 commit" part if they actually reference the commit.

Comment: If you name the branch according to the issue the branch will be visible in the jira issue as i describe in the question but commits that does not follow this naming convention will not be visible even though the commits are attached to the branch. Perhaps im misunderstanding you. Could you elaborate?

Comment: They are visible if you click on the branch and open it.

Comment: You could create your own plugin and display commits based off of this https://github.com/osowskit/atlassian-github-app-addon