# Github comment format enforcement

Tags: git, github

We integrate Github with Jira. Is it possible to enforce a certain format when we perform commit/push? such as JIRA123 - XXXXXX

We did it back when we used Git, but now we use Github.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I connect github to JIRA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421647/how-do-i-connect-github-to-jira)

Comment: You may find the answer [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-hooks)